# Android: ProgressDialog not shown with AsyncTask

Tags: android

I'm trying to display a `ProgressDialog` in my `Activity` while I'm executing a task with `AsyncTask`. Here my code below.

My problem is that `onPreExecute()` is called (I checked it with print) but my `progressDialog` is not shown while my function `sendRequest` is executed in `doInBackground(..)`. I don't understand what it happens and I don't know how to solve that. I googled it but I didn't find any suitable solution. If you have any idea it would be great for me.

```
private static Activity activity;
private static ProgressDialog dialog;

public MyClass(Activity activity){
    this.activity = activity;
}
public static String sendRequest(String request){
//do something
}


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
   super.onPreExecute();
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity,
            "ProgressDialog",
            "Wait!");

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String result = sendRequest(params[0]);
    return result;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: How are you using `MyClass` ? Also there is nothing in `sendRequest()` method. Progress dialog is showing but it may be within a second. Perform some operations in `sendRequest` method.

Comment: There is something in sendRequest. I am performing an http request on a remote server. I am also using MyClass in my activity to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
progressDialog.setTitle("title");
progressDialog.setMessage("message");
progrsesDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(CardPaymentActivity.this,
                "Progress", "please wait...");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        publishProgress("sleep time..."); // Calls onProgressUpdate()
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... text) {

    }
}
```

and call AsyncTaskRunner class in your activity class like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_card_payment);

    AsyncTaskRunner myTask = new AsyncTaskRunner();
                myTask.execute();

}
```